# How to output PHP variable value within a string to be used as part of MySQL query?

Tags: php

how to get this case working in php?

Not working case (the one I want to work):
I have a table where I store where clause to be used in my php code.

It is stored as string in table's field `"WHERECLAUSE"`:

```
"where WEEK = '$weeknum'  AND YEAR = '$year'"
```

I select string value from table's field "WHERECLAUSE"  put into the variable

php code :

```
   $TABLE = 'REASSORT';
   $whereclause =  "where WEEK = '$weeknum'  AND YEAR = '$year'";

     // create the select query
   $query = "select * FROM $TABLE " . $whereclause;
```

when I `echo $query` I get -->

```
 select * FROM REASSORT where WEEK = '$weeknum'  AND YEAR = '$year'
```

This returns no data from table "REASSORT", because variables `$weeknum` and `$year` are rendered as strings.

working case I expect:

PHP code:

```
$whereclause = " where WEEK = '$weeknum'  AND YEAR = '$year' ";
$query = "select * FROM $TABLE " . $whereclause;
```

when I echo $query I get -->

```
select * FROM REASSORT where WEEK = '4' AND YEAR = '2019'
```

And data is returned from table "REASSORT"

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `$weeknum` and `$year` in double quotes(") instead of single quotes(') like below-

`$whereclause = 'where WEEK = "$weeknum" AND YEAR = "$year";`

As Variable under the single quotes will be considered as a string instead of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace single quote (') with double quote (" )

replace

```
$whereclause = " where WEEK = '$weeknum' AND YEAR = '$year' ";
```

with

```
$whereclause = ' where WEEK = "$weeknum" AND YEAR = "$year" ';
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't recognize `'$weeknum'` and  `'$year'` as variables. You should try using `eval()`, but be careful with this function.

```
$weeknum = 5;
$year = 2019;
$whereclause = "where WEEK = '$weeknum' AND YEAR = '$year'";

eval("\$whereclause = \"$whereclause\";");

$query = "select * FROM $TABLE " . $whereclause;
```

$query should then output:

```
"select * FROM REASSORT where WEEK = '5'  AND YEAR = '2019'"
```

Or use curly braces instead of single quotes.

So instead of: 
 `'$weeknum'` and  `'$year'`

should be 
 `{$weeknum}` and  `{$year}`

For details about `eval()` see: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

For using curly brackets see: 
https://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/usage-of-brackets/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) to force PHP to substitute the values of the variables into the `$whereclause` string. But be warned, `eval` can be dangerous if you don't know what might be in the value. This will work:

```
$query = "select * FROM $TABLE " . eval("return \"$whereclause\";");
echo $query;
```

Output:

```
select * FROM REASSORT where WEEK = '4' AND YEAR = '2019'
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/QaZg3)

Comment: Thanks, eval is the solution.

Comment: This is same answer I gave, but I gave earlier :) Nevermind

Comment: @Nick, no problem, I haven't wrote example immediately, but gave an exact point to eval() :) Np